# Enumerate in Abstract (scrartcl-class)

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate, abstract

When using the enumerate environment inside the abstract environment of the scrartcl-class, the intend for the first item does not match those of the following items:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{{\scshape I am Author}}
\title{This Is My Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item  \lipsum[2]
    \item  \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

How can be that changed to be consitently (e.g. like items 2-x)?

Comment: I removed the [tag:koma-script] tag because the standard classes show the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be solved by putting a `\noindent` command before the list.

```
\noindent\begin{enumerate}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem putting some words before `\begin{enumerate}` or putting `\noindent` command before the same environment.

**Solution 1:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{{\scshape I am Author}}
\title{This Is My Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Some words
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item  \lipsum[2]
    \item  \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{{\scshape I am Author}}
\title{This Is My Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item  \lipsum[2]
    \item  \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{abstract}


\end{document}
```